# Is it possible to monitor my Raspberry Pi based home servers remotely outside of my LAN?

Tags: linux, debian, monitoring, system-monitoring

I have Raspberry Pi home servers with a few services I care about. My Raspberry Pis live behind a router and are not available from the outside of my home network.

I am wondering, is it any light agent I can install on my Debian-based distro and monitor availability of my home servers? If it is possible to alert on conditions it would be even better!

Comment: at what level are you hoping to measure availability? just host-is-up on the network (eg ping) or do you want to check the services themselves? will a simple response work, or do you want to actually test service output beyond simple response codes?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to some web hosting (outside your LAN), a simple cron script on your pi could update a file visible on the web? Very crude but can be effective and doesnt require directly exposing your Pi to the internet.

For a more robust solution, and if you have an AWS account, you could try this [Systems Manager for Raspberry Pi guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/manage-raspberry-pi-devices-using-aws-systems-manager/). This allows you to manage systems (inside and outside of aws). This includes remote/scheduled command execution and workflows for patch management etc. You can also forward logs to AWS cloudwatch Logs and stats to CloudWatch (CPU/memory/disk etc), setup alarms based on those logs and send email alerts with AWS SES. If its just one Pi your monitoring, you would probably be within AWS' free tier or cost pennies a month at most.

Answer (score 1):

sure, use an open source system resource monitor. there are a few but these two see prominent, free and open-source:

- [Netdata](https://www.netdata.cloud/) (easy to install with wget script)
- [Zabbix](https://www.zabbix.com/download) (a little more involved)

Netdata's web-based monitoring will let you see the remote machine as long as it can report to the netdata cloud.